# how to decide point is between two points on compass

Tags: math, geometry

Given any two points on  compass (Start range and End Range) to form a range. Example from 270(Start range) degrees to 45(End range)degrees and given another point say 7 , how can I work out if that point is between Start and End range ?

I'm trying to write some code to work out if the Wind (in the above point 3) is blowing from the sea or from the land , where the land is defind by Start range  and End range .

Many Thanks
Andy

Update:11/10/2010 18:46BST
From @sth's solution the following seems to work for as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

sub isoffshore {

        my ( $beachstart,$beachend,$wind) = @_;

        if( $beachend < $beachstart) {
                $beachend += 360;
        }

        if ($wind < $beachstart){
                $wind += 360;
        }

        if ($wind <= $beachend){
                print ("Wind is Onshore\n");
                return 0;
        }else{
                print ("Wind is Offshore\n");
                return 1;

        }

}

isoffshore ("0","190","3"); #Should be onshore
isoffshore ("350","10","11"); #Should be offshore
isoffshore ("270","90","180");#Should be offshore
isoffshore ("90","240","0"); #Should be offshore
isoffshore ("270","90","180");#Should be offshore
isoffshore ("0","180","90"); #Should be onshore
isoffshore ("190","0","160"); #Should be offshore
isoffshore ("110","240","9"); #Should be offshore
isoffshore ("0","180","9"); #Should be onshore
isoffshore ("0","180","179"); #Should be onshore
```

Results

```
@localhost ~]$ ./offshore2.pl
Wind is Onshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Onshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Offshore
Wind is Onshore
Wind is Onshore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one line function which uses the modulo (`%`) operator to handle the wraparound case. Input values are assumed to be in the range 0..359 (degrees):

```
int inRange(int start, int end, int point)
{
    return (point + 360 - start) % 360 <= (end + 360 - start) % 360;
}

//
// Test harness
//

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(inRange(90, 270, 0) == 0);
    assert(inRange(90, 270, 45) == 0);
    assert(inRange(90, 270, 180) == 1);
    assert(inRange(90, 270, 315) == 0);
    assert(inRange(270, 90, 0) == 1);
    assert(inRange(270, 90, 45) == 1);
    assert(inRange(270, 90, 180) == 0);
    assert(inRange(270, 90, 315) == 1);

    if (argc >= 4)
    {
        int start = atoi(argv[1]);
        int end = atoi(argv[2]);
        int point = atoi(argv[3]);
        int result = inRange(start, end, point);

        printf("start = %d, end = %d, point = %d -> result = %d\n", start, end, point, result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `+ 360` term on each side of the test is required in C/C++ due to the unfortunate way that `%` treats negative values.

Comment: Very nice. Such a simple solution :-)

Comment: @AndyM: thanks - I was determined to come up with a branchless solution. It's a pity about the C/C++ % operator though - if it worked properly for negative values then the solution would have been simpler.

Answer (score 2):

By points on a compass, I assume that you mean points on the unit circle. And by "between" two points on the unit circle, you mean that you have described an arc on the unit circle and want to know if a given point is in that arc.

Assume that all points on the unit circle are described by angles and for such an angle `t` describing a point on the unit circle we require that `0 <= t < 2 * pi`.

Let's say that your arc is described as the arc `(t_1, t_2)` (that is, traverse **counterclockwise** from the point on the unit circle corresponding to the angle `t_1` to the point on the unit circle corresponding to the angle `t_2`<sup>*</sup>). Then, given a point on the unit circle with corresponding angle `t`, it is true that `t` is on the counterclockwise arc from `t_1` to `t_2` if `t_2 > t_1` and `t_1 <= t <= t_2` or `t_1 > t_2` and not `t_2 <= t <= t_1`.

Thus,

```
public bool IsInArc(double t1, double t2, double t) {
     Guard.Against<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(t1 < 0 || t1 >= 2 * Math.PI);
     Guard.Against<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(t2 < 0 || t2 >= 2 * Math.PI);
     Guard.Against<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(t < 0 || t >= 2 * Math.PI);
     return t2 > t1 ? IsInArcInternal(t1, t2, t) : !IsInArcInternal(t2, t1, t);
}

private bool IsInArcInternal(double t1, double t2, double t) {
     Guard.Against<ArgumentException>(t2 < t1);
     return t1 <= t && t <= t2;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. If t1 = 3*pi/2 and t2 = pi/2 and t is 0 then t is in the arc (starting at t1 and going clockwise past zero to t2). However, your technique suggests it is not. I believe your technique is not takign the arc defined clockwise from t1 but always whichever arc does not contain the zero point (ie does not wrap around). The only value of t1,t2 that allows the zero point to be included for yours is t1=0 or t2 = 0.

Comment: @Chris: Wrong. My method works for the situation that you have described. Note that in the case you describe, `t1 = 3 * pi / 2`, `t2 = pi / 2` and `t = 0`. Therefore, `t2 > t1` is false, so that `IsInArcInternal` is called as `IsInArcInternal(pi /2, 3 * pi / 2, 0)`. Then we have that `pi / 2 <= 0 && 0 <= 3 * pi / 2` is false`. But note that there is a `!` in front of the call to `IsInArcInternal` and therefore the return value of `IsInArc` is true. It's certainly possible I messed up some other cases, but this one is correct.

Comment: @Paul R: I don't agree. Please see my comment to Chris. Please note the `!` in front of the call to `IsInArcInternal` when `t2 <= t1`.

Comment: @Jason: sorry - I missed the `!` - unfortunately I can't remove the down-vote now as it's too old - apologies

Comment: @Jason: Ah yes, I did miss the not. Sorry. And this is why I never down vote without giving the person in question a chance to prove me wrong. :) I'll put a nice upvote in now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work if all your points are like `0 <= point < 360`:

```
def between(lower, upper, point):
   if upper < lower:
      upper += 360
   if point < lower:
      point += 360
   return (point <= upper)
```

Comment: This seems right but the upper and lower variable names seem a bit confusing. Maybe startRange and endRange would be a bit more intuitive. The check "upper < lower" just keeps making me lose the plot. :)

Comment: @sth, @Chris: This fails if `lower = 3 * pi /2`, `upper = 3 * pi / 2 - epsilon` and `point = 3 * pi / 2 - epsilon / 2` where `epsilon` is a small positive number. In this case, your algorithm would detect that `upper < lower` is true, would set `upper = 7 * pi / 2 - epsilon` and would then test if `3 * pi / 2 - epsilon / 2` is less than or equal to `7 * pi / 2 - epsilon`. As this is true, it would return `true`. However, `3 * pi / 2 - epsilon / 2` is not on the arc from `3 * pi / 2` to `3 * pi / 2 - epsilon`.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused as to why pi and epsilon got into this discussion ?

Comment: The solution seems to work for me. @Jason can you give an example where it will not work ?

Comment: My mistake. I inserted an `else` in my head. Please accept my sincerest apologies.

Comment: @AndyM: pi entered the discussion because Jason is using radians instead of degrees. Epsilon is just a variable that was being used to define the points he was talking about with a parameter rather than a static number.